# What is 'K' in the Bounded Post Correspondence Problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

I'm only just starting to learn about the PCP, and I'm especially interested in the Bounded version. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem#Variants):

> One of the most important variants of PCP is the bounded Post
>   correspondence problem, which asks if we can find a match using no
>   more than k tiles, including repeated tiles.

I am not sure I understand what Wiki means by a 'tile' in this context.

I do understand that a typical PCP problem takes as input two equal-length lists of nonempty strings, each of which contains some number of words. An example is this:

`M = (abb, aa, aaa)` and `N = (bba, aaa, aa)`

In terms of the Bounded PCP, what would the integer K be here? Is it the length an individual word can be (which in this case is maxed at 3)? Is it the length of a single list?

Hope this is clear. I appreciate any help profusely in advance.

Comment: You've flipped around the problem. You've given as input a pair of lists, but it takes as input a list of pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your list is M=(bba,ab,bba,a) N=(bb,aa,bb,baa) Then its equivalent tile representation is as follows

[image]

Now your pcp problem is equivalent to finding a sequence of tiles(repetition allowed) such that concatenating all upper halves and concatenating all lower halves gives you same string.
K here is nothing but number of tiles that can be used

Edit : As [Yuval Filmus](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/683/yuval-filmus) subtly mentions in his comment, there are many other interpretations of K. In an another formulation K can also be the maximum length of concatenated string, in which case the bounded PCP problem is Pspace complete. But usually many books refer to K as being number of tiles that are allowed.Please refer to Sipser book for more.

Comment: There might be several different definitions of bounded, see for example [this answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/4638/683). In particular, the Wikipedia definition seems to be different.

Comment: I would say something like "finding a multiset of tiles" instead, to stress you can repeat the same tile. If you can't then the problem becomes decidable.

Comment: sequence would be much better representation to insist on the order . Anyways thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For this version of the Bounded PCP, the question is whether we can find a matching solution using no more than k tiles, as opposed to the general PCP which allows an infinite supply of such tiles, right?

Comment: @Fiery Phoenix Yes thats true